# Can't select two objects in Edit Mode

Tags: selection-tools

Here is part of my bipedal dinosaur character, I want to select two objects in order to connect the hand to the arm, but so far it's only allowing me to edit one object. (I am also using a mirror modifier)

[image]

How could I select the two objects so I can attach the hand to the arm? I want to be able to connect vertices and faces together, if anyone could offer tips to do this it would also be a great help. Thanks for your responses in advance.

Comment: You have to join the two objects first. In object mode, select them both and use "Ctrl+J" (the last one selected in yellow will be the active object, so the other one will be joined to it)

Comment: Ah thank you! I tried that earlier, however the mirror image disappeared, I didn't realise I needed to select the body last in order for it to work. Thanks! :)