# How to edit two objects in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I have been following tutorials to help me make a player model. But somehow while making a hand to connect to the body I made it into 2 separate cubes so only one of them can be in edit mode at a time instead of both like before. How do I put them back on the same "layer" or whatever so I can have then both set to edit mode at the same time??

Comment: select both objects in object mode and join them (Ctrl+J). Also read the following link to understand the difference between objects and meshes. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107399/cant-select-two-objects-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 0):

Install this [addon](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtxbhxxw9qriti2/MultiEdit_1_0.zip?dl=0)

After installation you can find this addon in toolshelf -> tools -> multi object editing

[image]

**How to use**

Go to toolshelf -> tools -> multi object editing and Click on **Enable Multi Edit mode**

Select the objects that you need to edit same time.

Now go to toolshelf -> tools -> multi object editing and select **Multiedit enter** as soon as you click your are in edit mode and now you can edit the mesh which you have selected before.

After editing Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to be in object mode. When you click the objects look join to separate them.

Go to toolshelf -> tools -> multi object editing and select **Multiedit exit**

[image]